# webview doesn´t maximize with the screen in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Im working with scenebuilder and I want a my application to hava a lateral toolbar and a webview. The problem that I´m having is when I maximize the screen, the webview remains the same size while the pane get bigger. I have tried with Stackpane but it didn´t work. The structure right now looks something like this:

```
Pane
   VBox
   StackPane
      WebView
```

Edit: I have tried other things, for example this let me resize fine but the stackpane fills the entire screen, no place for the vBox

```
AnchorPane
   VBox
   StackPane
      WebView
```

My fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.BrowserController">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="vbox" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" />
<StackPane fx:id="subPane" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <WebView fx:id="webview" prefWidth="600.0" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `Pane` just resizes the children to the preferred sizes. You won't get a responsive layout with this layout...

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: But how can I achive something similar?

Comment: Post your `FXML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find some tutorialS about `JavaFX` layouts. If I understood you correctly, this should do the trick.  `VBox`, `HBox`, and `GridPane` are great for handling growing layouts. The key in this example is `HBox`. Setting the left `VBox` to a given width and set the `WebView` to `HBox.vgrow = "ALWAYS"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<VBox prefHeight="443.0" prefWidth="678.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.BrowserController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar>
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
         </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <VBox fx:id="vbox" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" />
            <WebView fx:id="webview" prefWidth="600.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```